# How to configure htaccess in Kirby CMS for single page app

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, kirby

I'm developing a single page app on top of Kirby CMS and need most pages to redirect to the homepage so that I can handle the routing in the frontend.

Some pages i.e. /api__data and everything related to the panel still need to be accessible through Kirby though.

I'm having trouble configuring the .htaccess file to implement the correct redirects.

Currently the .htaccess looks like this:

```
# Kirby .htaccess

# rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# enable awesome urls. i.e.:
# http://yourdomain.com/about-us/team
RewriteEngine on

# make sure to set the RewriteBase correctly
# if you are running the site in a subfolder.
# Otherwise links or the entire site will break.
#
# If your homepage is http://yourdomain.com/mysite
# Set the RewriteBase to:
#
# RewriteBase /mysite

# In some enviroments it's necessary to
# set the RewriteBase to:
#
# RewriteBase /

# block text files in the content folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ index.php [L]

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
# except for requests to plugin assets files
#RewriteRule ^assets/plugins/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_%=]+)/(.*)$ site/plugins/$1/assets/$2 [L,N]
#RewriteCond $1 !^plugins/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_%=]+/assets/.*
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) index.php [L]

# block direct access to kirby and the panel sources
RewriteRule ^(kirby|panel\/app|panel\/tests)/(.*) index.php [L]

# make panel links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*) panel/index.php [L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# Additional recommended values
# Remove comments for those you want to use.
#
# AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
#
# php_flag short_open_tag on
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to make the single page app thing work I didn't have to edit the htaccess file after all. I added the following line into the site.php file (in the visit function):

```
if (!preg_match("/api_/i", $uri)) {
  return $this->page = $this->homePage();
}
```

This ensures that all urls are redirected to home (except my api calls)